# "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'op' was corrupted" Error (C language)

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am pretty new in C and I came across this problem and didn't understand why does this happen. After I run the following code there's an error message which says:
"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'op' was corrupted".

FYI, the program should ask the user for 2 integers and a mathtematical operator, and then it performs the operation on the two numbers (e.g 5,3,+ --> 5+3=8). It works just fine, except the error message that pops in the end.
I'm only interested in understanding why this message pops, there is no need to give me notes about my coding style etc. - it is all still new to me...
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void askUser();
double calculateImpl(int *, char *);

typedef struct _myStruct
{
    double result;
    double(*calculate) (int *, char *);
} myStruct;

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello World!");
    askUser();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



void askUser(){
    int numbers[2] = { 0, 0 };
    char op[1] = { '.' };
    printf("Please choose 2 integers:\n");
    printf("1st integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &numbers[0]);
    printf("\n2nd integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &numbers[1]);
    printf("\nchoose a mathematical operator\n(+,-,*,/; can't choose / if the second number is 0: ");
    scanf("%s", &op[0]);
    while (numbers[1] == 0 && op[0] == '/'){
        printf("\ncan't choose / while the second number is 0.\nchoose a different operation: ");
        scanf("%s", &op[0]);
    }
    printf("the result of %d %s %d is ", numbers[0], &op[0], numbers[1]);
    myStruct strct;
    strct.calculate = calculateImpl;
    strct.result = strct.calculate(numbers, op);
    printf("%lf\n", strct.result);

}

double calculateImpl(int * numbers, char * op){
    double result = 0;
    switch (op[0])
    {
    case '+':
        result = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
        break;
    case '-':
        result = numbers[0] - numbers[1];
        break;
    case '*':
        result = numbers[0] * numbers[1];
        break;
    case '/':
        result = numbers[0] / numbers[1];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return result;
```

}

Comment: You have defined 'char op[1]' and using scanf("%s", &op[0]); --> NOTE that when scanning as string, your 'op' array does not have space for terminating '\0' character. scanf("%s", ...) will scan input character array and terminate with '\0'. This is resulting in stack corruption around 'op' problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 scanf("%s", &op[0]);
         ^ use %c
```

Use `%c` specifier to take input in character variable .  You pass wring argument to `%s` specifier.

Also there is `scanf` in `while` loop , use correct specifier there also .

Declare `op` as `char` -

```
char op;                // you don't need char op[1]
```

Wrtie like this -

```
 scanf(" %c", &op);           // at both places
```

And inside after loop this line -

```
 printf("the result of %d %s %d is ", numbers[0], &op[0], numbers[1]);
```

To print `char` don't pass its address and use `%c` -

```
 printf("the result of %d %c %d is ", numbers[0], op, numbers[1]);
```

Also then pass your function `char` not `char *` -

```
double calculateImpl(int *, char );
```

and make changes accordingly in your program.

Comment: I can't get an operator from users using "%c". the error message does not appear however...

Comment: @noamgot You put a space before `%c` in `scanf` right ?

Comment: @noamgot And to your function pass `char` not `char *` and declare `op` as `char op` .

Comment: @noamgot after two previous two `scanf` whem you press enter `'\n'` and `%c` reads them and `scanf` returns with input .